# KnockoutJS show/hide div based on string

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have a model knockoutJS model having the following structure:

```
this.optionGroup = ko.obervable({});
```

And there is an option in this object called isAvailable and its value is either "true" or "false".

The problem I am having is to show Yes in case of "true" and No in case of "false" so that it would be more friendly to the user.  I have tried various options, with the last one being the following:

```
<div data-bind="text: optionGroup().isAvailable === 'true'? 'Yes' : 'No'"></div>
```

Unfortunately this is always evaluating to false, and thus showing 'No' in the HTML.  This is my first time using knockoutJS as this is a legacy page, and not sure if there's a way to easily show Yes/No label based on the value set in isAvailable.

Thanks

Comment: What you have is fine. If it's always showing "No" that means one of the following: 1) There is no `isAvailable` on the object (as is the case with the one you show at the top of the question). 2. There is but its value isn't the **string** `true` (perhaps it's a boolean?). 3. `isAvailable` is observable, in which case you have to unwrap it whenever you involve it in an expression just like you did with `optionGroup`, so `optionGroup().isAvailable() === 'true' ? ...`). (And if it's really a string, consider refactoring that. true/flase should be booleans, not strings.)

Comment: `isAvailable === 'true'` looks suspect. Are you sure you want to test for the string `'true'` without any kind of coercion? Does `isAvailable == 'true'` work by any chance?

Comment: While it's fine, for this sort of thing I try to keep the logic out of the HTML by putting it in a computed. In the model: `this.optionGroupAvailableText = ko.pureComputed(function() { return /*...the calculation...*/; }, this);` and then in the HTML: `text: optionGroupAvailableText`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  The value is always a string, infact although that value would be received as part of an ajax call, I am hard coding it for now.  I am setting the value like this:
object.isAvailable = "true"
model.optionGroup(ko.mapping.fromJS(object));

(object is the response of an ajax call, and above I am hardcoding the value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment:

> I am setting the value like this: `object.isAvailable = "true" model.optionGroup(ko.mapping.fromJS(object));` (`object` is the response of an ajax call, and above I am hardcoding the value).

That means `isAvailable` is an observable, since that's the job of the mapping plugin. So my #3 from [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48546351/knockoutjs-show-hide-div-based-on-string#comment84088708_48546351) applies, you want:

```
<div data-bind="text: ko.unwrap(optionGroup().isAvailable) === 'true'? 'Yes' : 'No'"></div>
```

Or if you're **always** going to make sure you've made that `mapper` call before the view renders, you can use `()` instead of `ko.unwrap`:

```
<div data-bind="text: optionGroup().isAvailable() === 'true'? 'Yes' : 'No'"></div>
```

My first version uses `ko.unwrap` because in your initial `optionGroup` object, there's no `isAvilable` at all, so if we just used `.isAvailable()`, it would throw, whereas `ko.unwrap(...)` won't.

---

Or as I said in a separate comment, a computed instead:

```
this.optionGroup = ko.obervable({});
this.optionGroupAvailableText = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return ko.unwrap(this.optionGroup().isAvailable) === 'true'? 'Yes' : 'No';
}, this);
```

then:

```
<div data-bind="text: optionGroupAvailableText"></div>
```